# zf2 getServiceLocator() return null

Tags: php, zend-framework2

The controller ,getServiceLocator return null.

```
namespace Test\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller;
use Test\Model\Test;

class TestController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $db;
    private function get_db()
    {
        if (!$this->db) {
           $this->db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db1');
        }
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

/config/autoload/databae.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'adapters' => array(
            'db1' => array(
                'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
                'driver' => 'mysqli',
                'port' => '3308',
                'database' => 'test',
                'username' => 'test',
                'password' => 'test',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'options' => array(
                    'buffer_results' => true
                )
            ),
            'db2' => array(
                'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
                'driver' => 'pdo',
                'database' => 'test',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'options' => array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
        )
    ),
```

The result

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   /home/test/zf2/module/Test/src/Test/Controller/TestController.php on
>   line 16

Comment: Can you please show us more code about your app? If this is your WHOLE controller, then it is NOT a controller. It is just a class. Where are you calling the function `get_db()` from?

Comment: Thank you,I have found the problem.I want to develop a cli application,so I didn't use entrance /public/index.php ,but the entrance test.php. The test.php  without
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();  .Now I use /public/index.php as the entrance,and I use Zend/console to develop the cli application.